# How can I solve this end of line?

Tags: equations, minipage, line

[image: I using \text{} command]

If is possible without leaving the equation environment

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
$\displaystyle\text{Se sabe del T. de Cauchy:}\\\\\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz=(2\pi i)f(z_0)\\\\ \Rightarrow f(z)=e^{-z}\\\\
\text{La curva es cerrada y suave y}
\frac{1}{e^z (z-2)}\text{ es analítica sobre la curva\\\\ $\gamma$ , pero no es analítica en 2.}
f(z)=\frac{\sin(e^z+\cos z )}{z+3}\\\\\rightarrow f'(z)=\frac{(e^2-\sin z )(\cos(e^z+\cos z ))}{z+3}\\\\\\
\Rightarrow \frac{2\pi i}{1!}\frac{(e^2-\sin 1 )(\cos(e^1+\cos 1 ))}{1+3}=4.24i
$\\\\\\
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: thanks,, @Bernard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not include all `minipage` content into math environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
Se sabe del T. de Cauchy:
\begin{align*}
\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz
    & = (2\pi i)f(z_0)                              \\
    & \Rightarrow f(z)=e^{-z}
\end{align*}
La curva es cerrada y suave y $\frac{1}{e^z (z-2)}$ es analítica sobre la curva $\gamma$, pero no es analítica en 2.
\begin{align*}
f(z) 
    & = \frac{\sin(e^z+\cos z )}{z+3} \rightarrow   \\
f'(z)
    & = \frac{(e^2-\sin z )(\cos(e^z+\cos z ))}{z+3} \\
    & \Rightarrow 
        \frac{2\pi i}{1!}\frac{(e^2-\sin 1 )(\cos(e^1+\cos 1 ))}{1+3}\\
    & = 4.24i
\end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

gives  correct result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for you time, it see good, i like it, although I have long preferred `$` to `\begin {equation*}`, this time I will try it your way, the right way. gl.

Comment: @Libreik, in my example are not any `equation*` environment but `align*` defined in the package `amsmath`. It enables to write multi line equations aligned at anchors &, what with `$` is not possible. Your MWE worked just by accident.

Comment: yes i know it. thanks..xD